# I get an Error when I try to follow Tor browser bundle instructions...help?

Tags: tor

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and i'm trying to get Tor Browser Bundle. i've downloaded the package and then the [tor project website](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux) tells me to put this in my terminal

```
tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-3.5_LANG.tar.xz
```

I tried that but it gave me this ERR0R:

```
tar (child): tor-browser-linux32-3.5_LANG.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

..Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term `LANG` in `tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-3.5_LANG.tar.xz` stands for the language of the bundle. So if you downloaded the [english version](https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/3.5/tor-browser-linux32-3.5_en-US.tar.xz) you would have to substitute `LANG` by `en-US`. The correct command in this case is

```
tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-3.5_en-US.tar.xz
```

Comment: Your suggestion really helped (with LANG substitution and BYEAskUbuntu helped with his "~Desktop/" Thanks!

Comment: We are glad that you have solved your  issue

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons we have here with solutions.

1. You may have not doing the TAR for tor in the proper directory where exactly you have placed tor . so make sure that you are doing extraction from the correct directory where you have placed Tor.
2. The downloaded tor might get corrupted, so you better redownload and try again.

Comment: It's on my desktop. How would i write the path for that?

Comment: Then it would be as `tar -xvJf ~/Desktop/tor-browser-linux32-3.5_LANG.tar.xz`  @CollinBlatt

Comment: I re-downloaded it and then I tried the code you gave above...but same error.